# Building FFTW 3.3.3 for iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, fftw

I want to build FFTW library for iPhone and use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SDKVER="6.0"
export DEVROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer"
export SDKROOT="$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS$SDKVER.sdk"

export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -isysroot $SDKROOT"
export LDFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wl,-syslibroot $SDKROOT"

export CC=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld

export PREFIX="$HOME/Desktop/mylib"

./configure --prefix="$PREFIX" --enable-single --host=arm-apple-darwin
make
make install
```

Then I import libfftw3f.a and fftw3.h in Xcode in my project, link this library in Build Phases.

When I try to compile, Xcode gives me this warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Adem/Desktop/mylib/lib/libfftw3f.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/Adem/Desktop/mylib/lib/libfftw3f.a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What size fft do you need to do?  The accelerate framework (which is part of the OS) provides a fft implementation supporting many common sizes without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-arch armv7` to your CFLAGS (and hence also to your LDFLAGS)